# jQuery issue when doing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to do a form validation with jQuery validation files. It's giving me a hard time...
It's a simple form, what I'm doing now is to check that username imput:

- can't start with a number
- can't be only numbers
- can't start with a symbol
- can't be only symbols
- should be like this example: username = panchi15_ or jack or a77

This is html snippet:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6 ">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Usuario<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="m-wrap span8" required/>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

at the top of this file i'm calling following files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{site_url()}assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{site_url()}assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

my js file:

```
var FormValidation = function () {

var handleValidation2 = function() {
    // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

        var form2 = $('#form-val');
        var error2 = $('.alert-error', form2);
        var success2 = $('.alert-success', form2);

        //IMPORTANT: update CKEDITOR textarea with actual content before submit
        form2.on('submit', function() {
            for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
            }
        })

        form2.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                //utilizo el plugin additional-methods.js para crear algunas reglas y validar
                username: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    // pattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*",
                    //el nombre de usuario no puede empezar con numeros
                    // pattern: "/^!=.*\d\w{2,15}$/",
                    pattern: true,
                    required: true

                },

                name: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    // regex: ,
                    required: true
                },

                lastname: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    required: true
                },

                gender: {
                    required: true
                },

                date_born: {
                    required: true
                },

                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },

                status: {
                    required: true
                },

                member_id: {
                    minlength: 5,
                },

                documentType_id: {
                    required: true
                },

                documentn: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                address_street: {
                    required: true
                },

                address_number: {
                    required: true
                },

                address_floor: {
                    required: false
                },

                zipcode: {
                    required: true
                },

                city: {
                    required: true
                },

                state: {
                    required: true
                },

                country_id: {
                    required: true
                },

                phone: {
                    required: true
                },

                cellphoneNumber: {
                    required: true
                },

                cellCompany: {
                    required: true
                },

                cellbrand: {
                    required: true
                },

                marital_status: {
                    required: true
                },

                sons: {
                    required: true
                },
            },

            messages: { // custom messages for radio buttons and checkboxes
                username: {
                    // required: "Este campo es requerido",
                    minlength: "Mínimo 2 caracteres",
                    maxlength: "Máximo 15 caracteres",  
                    // remote: "No Disponible"

                },

                membership: {
                    required: "Please select a Membership type"
                },
                service: {
                    required: "Please select  at least 2 types of Service",
                    minlength: jQuery.format("Please select  at least {0} types of Service")
                }
            },

            // errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            //     if (element.attr("name") == "education") { // for chosen elements, need to insert the error after the chosen container
            //         error.insertAfter("#form_2_education_chzn");
            //     } else if (element.attr("name") == "membership") { // for uniform radio buttons, insert the after the given container
            //         error.addClass("no-left-padding").insertAfter("#form_2_membership_error");
            //     } else if (element.attr("name") == "editor1" || element.attr("name") == "editor2") { // for wysiwyg editors
            //         error.insertAfter($(element.attr('data-error-container'))); 
            //     } else if (element.attr("name") == "service") { // for uniform checkboxes, insert the after the given container
            //         error.addClass("no-left-padding").insertAfter("#form_2_service_error");
            //     } else {
            //         error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavior
            //     }
            // },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                success2.hide();
                error2.show();
                App.scrollTo(error2, -200);
            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.help-inline').removeClass('ok'); // display OK icon
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            success: function (label) {
                if (label.attr("for") == "service" || label.attr("for") == "membership") { // for checkboxes and radio buttons, no need to show OK icon
                    label
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                    label.remove(); // remove error label here
                } else { // display success icon for other inputs
                    label
                        .addClass('valid').addClass('help-inline ok') // mark the current input as valid and display OK icon
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success'); // set success class to the control group
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                success2.show();
                error2.hide();
            }

        });

        // $('#form-val').select2({
        //     placeholder: "Select an Option",
        //     allowClear: true
        // });

        // //apply validation on chosen dropdown value change, this only needed for chosen dropdown integration.
        // $('.chosen, .chosen-with-diselect', form2).change(function () {
        //     form2.validate().element($(this)); //revalidate the chosen dropdown value and show error or success message for the input
        // });

        //  //apply validation on select2 dropdown value change, this only needed for chosen dropdown integration.
        // $('.select2', form2).change(function () {
        //     form2.validate().element($(this)); //revalidate the chosen dropdown value and show error or success message for the input
        // });
}

return {
    // main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {           
        handleValidation2();
    }
};
}();
```

If user enters a valid username, then a green ok icon should appear next to the imput. Otherwise the input box should be in red with a legend telling which the error is.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/jimena/wXm3p/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I'm sorry but i need to call two javascript files in order to do this, jsfiddle I believe can't make it

Comment: you can create a jsfiddle with external javascript files. there is a field for external resources on the left side of jsfiddle page

Comment: @arun15thmay you are right. I'm doing it

Comment: Did you try using [addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod) to create a custom validation function?

Comment: @SalmanA I wanted to use the one that is included in the file additional methods, so I don't have repeated code

Comment: I believe you are missing the for attribute on your label. Please see the following example - http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html

Comment: The requirements are a bit redundant: If it can't start with a number, then you already don't have to worry about it being all numbers, ditto symbols.

Comment: @towr but the numers or symbols can be after the string

Comment: Yes, but the string can't be all numbers (symbols) unless the first character is a number (symbol).

Comment: @Gjohn thx, I'm looking at it. One thing, it doesn't call the additional-methods.js, which is the file I included

Comment: @towr so how the regular expression can be?

Comment: @Gjohn hey, I've tried with and without for attribute, but it's the same thing. I guess it's only necessary for certain kind of situations

Comment: @Limon You can use the pattern `[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*` You can add more symbols in the last character class, I only added _ because I don't know which you want.

Comment: @towr great. But if i want to include . and - (in the middle not at the end), and _ can be at the end, how can i change your reg expression?

Comment: You could use `[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\.\-_]*[0-9a-zA-Z_]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my question in case somebody else need it in the future. I could find out what I was doing wrong.

In one of the jQuery validation files, additional-methods.js, there is this function associated with word pattern:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("pattern", function(value, element, param) {
if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
}
if (typeof param === 'string') {
    param = new RegExp('^(?:' + param + ')$');
}
return param.test(value);
 }, "Invalid format.");
```

As you can see it receive 3 parameters, value, element and param. Param is the regular expression you define in order to match predefined elements already in the code line:

```
param = new RegExp('^(?:' + param + ')$');
```

In the js file i created, that you can see on my question, used only this:

```
   pattern: "[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*"
```

ANd that's it.

Comment: That pattern matches things starting with numbers. I thought you didn't want that?

Comment: @towr yes, then i realized that and changed to: pattern: "[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*"

Comment: You can simplify that to `[A-z]([\._\-]?[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*`  the `?` operator gives 0 or 1 repeats

Comment: @towr thank you for the patience. I'm gonna use this

Comment: Another question, there are some symbols between Z and a, do you mean to include those when you do `[A-z]`  ?

Comment: @towr yes, you can have . or - or _ between the letters, not at the start and only _ at the end (several repetitions of it)

Comment: I meant that `[A-z]` includes the characters ``[\]^_` `` because they're between `A-Z` and `a-z`, so it will match `]` among other things. Just try it at http://regexpal.com/